# Remove duplicates in an object array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects

```
list = [{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}, {x:1,y:2}]
```

And I'm looking for an efficient way (if possible `O(log(n))`) to remove duplicates and to end up with

```
list = [{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}]
```

I've tried `_.uniq` or even `_.contains` but couldn't find a satisfying solution.

Thanks!

Edit : The question has been identified as a duplicate of another one. I saw this question before posting but it didn't answer my question since it's an array of object (and not a 2-dim array, thanks Aaron), or at least the solutions on the other question weren't working in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: Note that this is not a 2-dimensional array but rather an array of objects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Vanilla JS version:

```js
const list = [{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}, {x:1,y:2}];

function dedupe(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(p, c) {

    // create an identifying id from the object values
    var id = [c.x, c.y].join('|');

    // if the id is not found in the temp array
    // add the object to the output array
    // and add the key to the temp array
    if (p.temp.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      p.out.push(c);
      p.temp.push(id);
    }
    return p;

    // return the deduped array
  }, {
    temp: [],
    out: []
  }).out;
}

console.log(dedupe(list));
```

Answer (score 40):

Plain javascript (ES2015), using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const list = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }];

const uniq = new Set(list.map(e => JSON.stringify(e)));

const res = Array.from(uniq).map(e => JSON.parse(e));

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: `stringify` and `parse` don't look like the most performant way to achieve this.

Comment: @AminJafari There's nothing with var usage even in 2020. As long as scoping is taken care, var is absolutely fine. While this answer is not the most performant it works as per OP's question

Comment: @SeaWarrior404 I know, that's why I upvoted :) It's just not a good practice to use var where you can use const

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is a correct, generic way to identify distinct objects with equal contents. However, most answers that use `JSON.stringify`, including this one, only work if the keys are always specified in the same order. See my answer on how to use a replacer function so that the solution even works when the order of the keys varies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71102751/1166087.

Answer (score 32):

Try using the following:

```
list = list.filter((elem, index, self) => self.findIndex(
    (t) => {return (t.x === elem.x && t.y === elem.y)}) === index)
```

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks

Comment: Just a question, can't you just use `Object.is()` for your filter's comparison?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: Hello! I've never seen `self` used before as in `.filter((elem, index, self) =>` what does self refer to? I get that  element refers to the element value and index to its position in the array. Or if someone could point me in the direction of docs that'd be great!

Answer (score 14):

I would use a combination of `Arrayr.prototype.reduce` and `Arrayr.prototype.some` methods with spread operator.

**1. Explicit solution**. Based on complete knowledge of the array object contains.

```
list = list.reduce((r, i) => 
  !r.some(j => i.x === j.x && i.y === j.y) ? [...r, i] : r
, [])
```

Here we have strict limitation on compared objects structure: `{x: N, y: M}`. And `[{x:1, y:2}, {x:1, y:2, z:3}]` will be filtered to `[{x:1, y:2}]`.

**2. Generic solution, `JSON.stringify()`**. The compared objects could have any number of any properties.

```
list = list.reduce((r, i) => 
  !r.some(j => JSON.stringify(i) === JSON.stringify(j)) ? [...r, i] : r
, [])
```

This approach has a limitation on properties order, so `[{x:1, y:2}, {y:2, x:1}]` won't be filtered.

**3. Generic solution, `Object.keys()`**. The order doesn't matter.

```
list = list.reduce((r, i) => 
  !r.some(j => !Object.keys(i).some(k => i[k] !== j[k])) ? [...r, i] : r
, [])
```

This approach has another limitation: compared objects must have the same list of keys.
So `[{x:1, y:2}, {x:1}]` would be filtered despite the obvious difference.

**4. Generic solution, `Object.keys()`** + **`.length`**.

```
list = list.reduce((r, i) => 
  !r.some(j => Object.keys(i).length === Object.keys(j).length 
    && !Object.keys(i).some(k => i[k] !== j[k])) ? [...r, i] : r
, [])
```

With the last approach objects are being compared by the number of keys, by keys itself and by key values.

I created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zqak8N?p=preview) to play with it.

Comment: Can you please explain what's happening in the 4th approach, especially with the array part and the some comparison? Its a bit dense to understand

Comment: @SeaWarrior404 The 4 approach is a combination of keys/values comparison presented as the second "some" taken from p.3 AND length comparison presented as the first "some", which iteratively compares the length of the keys of each object in the initial array with the length of the keys of all other objects in the initial array to make sure that all items in the list have the same number of fields. If a given object has the same number of fields as the others in the list, it will be sent to the key-values comparison (the second "some"). If not, it will be filtered out immediately.

Comment: You don't need to recreate an array at each iteration. you can use `r.push(i)` instead. `if (!r.some(j => JSON.stringify(i) === JSON.stringify(j))) r.push(i); return r`

Comment: thumbs up for the generic solution, just what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

**One liners for ES6+**

If you want to find uniq by x and y:

```
arr.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(t.x === v.x && t.y===v.y))===i)
```

If you want to find uniques by all properties:

```
arr.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(t=>(JSON.stringify(t) === JSON.stringify(v)))===i)
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will work:

```
var a = [{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}, {x:1,y:2}];

var b = _.uniq(a, function(v) { 
    return v.x && v.y;
})

console.log(b);  // [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 } ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me, is it faster than Andy's solution ?

Comment: I have no idea. It's less code to write and underscore seems to be included either way... @kwn

Comment: Unless you're dealing with 10s of 1000s of elements, performance shouldn't be an issue. I guess you have to weigh up the cost of loading a separate library (if lodash isn't in your stack already) or just using a slightly more verbose vanilla function.

Comment: fwiw @kwn, you could replace `reduce` in mine with a `for...loop` to maybe see an increase in performance, but it will be pretty much negligible.

Comment: Don't think this works properly e.g. 1 && 2 == 2 && 2

Comment: Me too, but that's not part of the question, nor the answer @GruffBunny

Comment: Surely the solution should work for all possible values not just for the values in the question.

Comment: Your comparison is completely unrelated to the answer @GruffBunny

Comment: If the input was [{x:1, y: 2}, {x: 2. y:2}] then the result would be [{x:1, y:2}] - the second object would be removed even though it's not a duplicate

Comment: @GruffBunny yeah I just saw that. I have the very same problem when I try to filter with one more value. e.g `test = [[1,{x:2,y:3}], [1, {x:2, y:4}], [2, {x:2,y:3}],[1, {x:2, y:4}] ]`, `_.uniq(test, function(v){return (v[1].x && v[1].y && v[0]);})` will return `[[1,{x:2,y:3}], [2, {x:2,y:3}] ]` instead of `[[1,{x:2,y:3}], [1, {x:2, y:4}], [2, {x:2,y:3}]`

Answer (score 4):

Filter the array after checking if already in a temorary object in O(n).

```js
var list = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 1, y: 2 }],
    filtered = function (array) {
        var o = {};
        return array.filter(function (a) {
            var k = a.x + '|' + a.y;
            if (!o[k]) {
                o[k] = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
    }(list);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

No libraries, and works with any depth

**Limitation:**

- You must provide only `string` or `Number` properties as hash objects otherwise you'll get inconsistent results

```js
/** 
 * Implementation, you can convert this function to the prototype pattern to allow
 * usage like `myArray.unique(...)`
 */ 
function unique(array, f) {
  return Object.values(
    array.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [f(item).join(``)]: item }), {})
  );
}

const list = [{ x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 4}, { x: 5, y: 6}, { x: 1, y: 2}];

// Usage
const result = unique(list, item => [item.x, item.y]);

// Output: [{ x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 4}, { x: 5, y: 6}]
console.log(result);
```

### Snippet Sample

```js
// Implementation
function unique(array, f) {
  return Object.values(
    array.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [f(item).join(``)]: item }), {})
  );
}

// Your object list
const list = [{ x: 1, y: 2}, {x: 3, y: 4}, { x: 5, y: 6}, { x: 1, y: 2}];

// Usage
const result = unique(list, item => [item.x, item.y]);

// Add result to DOM
document.querySelector(`p`).textContent = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Underscore's `_.uniq` and the standard `JSON.stringify` it is a oneliner:

```js
var list = [{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}, {x:1,y:2}];

var deduped = _.uniq(list, JSON.stringify);

console.log(deduped);
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

However, this presumes that the keys are always specified in the same order. By sophisticating the iteratee, we can make the solution work even if the order of the keys varies. This problem as well as the solution also apply to other answers that involve `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var list = [{x:1,y:2}, {x:3,y:4}, {x:5,y:6}, {y:2, x:1}];

// Ensure that objects are always stringified
// with the keys in alphabetical order.
function replacer(key, value) {
    if (!_.isObject(value)) return value;
    var sortedKeys = _.keys(value).sort();
    return _.pick(value, sortedKeys);
}

// Create a modified JSON.stringify that always
// uses the above replacer.
var stringify = _.partial(JSON.stringify, _, replacer, null);

var deduped = _.uniq(list, stringify);

console.log(deduped);
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

For Lodash 4, use `_.uniqBy` instead of `_.uniq`.

Answer (score -2):

Using lodash you can use this one-liner:

```
 _.uniqBy(list, e => { return e.x && e.y })
```